# AzCopy V10 Download Directory containing over a Million Files

Tags: azure, azcopy

I have a directory with over a million files.  I can selectively download a file without any issues using this command:

`azcopy copy https://XXXXX/YYYY/10000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 C:\temp\YYYY`

However, when I try to selectively download files based on a pattern, I get an error.  This is the command I used:

`azcopy copy  https://XXXXX/YYYY C:\temp\YYYY --recursive  --include-pattern '1000*'`

I get the following error:

```
Description=Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Time:2019-11-20T16:24:57.6698636Z, Details:
   AuthenticationErrorDetail: Issuer validation failed. Issuer did not match.
   Code: AuthenticationFailed
   GET https://XXXXX/YYYY?comp=list&include=metadata&restype=container&timeout=901
   Authorization: REDACTED
   User-Agent: [AzCopy/10.3.2 Azure-Storage/0.7 (go1.13; Windows_NT)]
   X-Ms-Client-Request-Id: [zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz]
   X-Ms-Version: [2018-03-28]
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   RESPONSE Status: 403 Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
   Content-Length: [422]
   Content-Type: [application/xml]
   Date: [Wed, 20 Nov 2019 16:24:57 GMT]
   Server: [Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0]
   X-Ms-Error-Code: [AuthenticationFailed]
   X-Ms-Request-Id: [zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz]
```

Any ideas on what I can try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `--include-pattern`, you should use **double quotes** to embrace the value, like **"1000*"**, not **'1000*'**.

And also use the latest version 10.3.2 of azcopy, follow [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Ffiles%2Ftoc.json#download-azcopy) to download.

Here are the steps I followed, and works fine:

1.In azure portal -> nave to your storage account -> in the left pane, click "Shared access signature", then generate a sas-token(you should copy the sas token, which can be used in step2). Screenshot as below:

[image]

2.Then build your source url, like https://yy3.blob.core.windows.net/t11/folder1/folder2?sas-Token.

3.The complete command like below, note use **double quotes** for the value of `--include-pattern`:

```
azcopy.exe copy "https://yy3.blob.core.windows.net/test1/folder1/folder2?sas-token" C:\temp\YYYY --recursive --include-pattern "1000*"
```

4.The test result as below, only the matched files are copies:

[image]

Comment: Even though I had the role owner, I did not have permission to list the directory.  Using the Shared Access Signature got me around the security restriction.